# Inserir registro automaticamente ao fazer um Insert PL/SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, pl-sql, trigger

Estou começando a mexer com banco de dados *PL/SQL* e estou com uma dificuldade em criar um *trigger* que ao inserir um linha na tabela, o *trigger* coloque um valor na minha coluna cujo nome é *token*.

Fiz um código com o que sei de *DB*, mas quando eu rodo apresenta o seguinte erro:

> ```
> (ORA-04084: não pode alterar valores NEW para este tipo de gatilho)
> ```

**Segue o código:**

```
create TABLE BancoJulianaCadastro(
codUser integer,
nome varchar(200),
senha varchar(50),
login varchar(8),
email varchar(30),
cpf number(11)
token number(20));

alter table BancoJulianaCadastro add CONSTRAINT codUser_PK PRIMARY key (codUser);

create sequence token_seq
minvalue 1
maxvalue 99999
start with 1
increment by 1;



create or replace trigger token_tgr 
AFTER INSERT ON BancoJulianaCadastro

declare
  sequencial number;
begin
   select token_seq.NEXTVAL
    into sequencial
   from dual;  
  :new.token := sequencial;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso, você pode usar uma trigger BEFORE ao invés de AFTER e pode atribuir a sequence diretamente ao campo :new.token. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TOKEN_TGR
BEFORE INSERT ON BancoJulianaCadastro
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   :NEW.TOKEN := TOKEN_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

Mas se for possível, seria interessante passar a sequence (TOKEN_SEQ.NEXTVAL) já durante o insert, dessa forma não precisaria dessa trigger e o código de insert ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
INSERT INTO TESTE_TRIGGER (CODUSER, NOME, SENHA, LOGIN, EMAIL, CPF, TOKEN)
VALUES (1234, 'JO SOARES', 'PASSWORD', 'JOSOARES', 'email@teste.com', '99999999999', TOKEN_SEQ.NEXTVAL );
```